# How to filter records from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

How to get records from association? I have 4 jobs in my jobs table.How to filter all jobs with resource_type_id=2. From the below records here for eg (I want to get job id with 2 and 3 as result).

Here is my association

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :jobs_resources   
  has_many :resource_type, through: :jobs_resources, dependent: :destroy   
end

class ResourceType < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :jobs_resources   
  has_many :jobs, through: :jobs_resources, dependent: :destroy end

class JobsResource < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :job   
  belongs_to :resource_type 
end
```

This is my how resources_type table is saved:

[image]

This is my JobsResource table records:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in below ways

```
Job.includes(:resource_type).where(resource_types: {id: 2}) 

Job.includes(:jobs_resources).where(jobs_resources: {resource_type_id: 2}) 

Job.joins(:jobs_resources).where(jobs_resources: {resource_type_id: 2})
```

Comment: getting this error when i tries to execute 2nd query,Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'resource_type.resource_type_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: first query gets this error, Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'resource_type.id' in 'where clause':

Comment: 2nd query is working thanks a lot Vishal :).. removed a big headache...thank youuuuuu

Comment: @SreRoR I think all of 3 should work, can you try all of them?

Comment: Third one, `where("jobs_resources.id = ?", 2)` make it as prepared statement.

Comment: @Vishal 1st and 2nd works now, 3rd gives this errorNoMethodError: undefined method `left_outer_joins' for #<Class:0x007fa25ed89b88>

Comment: @SreRoR third one should also work , can you try `Job.left_outer_joins(:resource_type).where("resource_types.id = 2")` or post error whole error here
`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
Job.joins(:resource_type).where('resource_types.id = ?', 2).load
```

Comment: this too works fine. Thank you :) , but works with association name modified like resource_type, Job.joins(:resource_type).where('resource_types.id = ?', 2).load

Comment: could you please explain what actually load does here?

Comment: select jobs.* from jobs inner join job_resources jr on jr.job_id = jobs.id inner join resource_types rt on rt.id = jr.resource_type_id where  rt.id = 2

Comment: this loads records of jobs with resource_type_id = 2

Comment: @ Abolfazl Mahmoodi,Thanking you for sharing your valuable time for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve Job records with a resource_types  record associated with:

```
Job.joins(:resource_types)
```

if you need all resource_types records which don't have an association with job you can execute:

```
ResourceType.where(job: nil)
```

Comment: How this is supposed to be and an answer? OP asked to get filtered output for resource_type_id = 2

Comment: How does `ResourceType.where(job: nil)` OP?

Comment: `where(job: nil)` ? job is not specified column anyway.